# Possible BooBoo in docs.raku.org Variables page code under "Item and list assignment"

Tags: list, variables, assignment-operator, scalar

```
# ATTENTION: special declaration syntax! 
my ($g) = 7,8,9;               # list assignment to List with one element 
say $g;                        # OUTPUT:  «7␤» 
say ( ($g) ).VAR.^name         # OUTPUT:  «List␤»
```

1. Upon execution of this code the last line never OUTPUTs "List" but always OUTPUTs "Scalar"; the doc needs to be changed.
2. Why all the ()'s?  ($g).VAR.^name and $g.VAR.^name output the same?
3. Eratta: ^name needs a ";".

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: I'm both pointing out an error in the doc and asking why all the parenthesis.  What is the example trying to tell with the two sets of parenthesis?